# List Urls within a Webapp

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

How can I get a list of published urls in my java web application to ensure that there is no security risk and I'm not publishing the incorrect files/resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, if you generated a sitemap while running your web application locally, you would know all pages visible to the public upon publishing.

Comment: I haven't tried any of [these tools](https://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/wiki/SitemapGenerators), nor tried to generate a sitemap locally (outside of Jekyll's automatic tooling), but here's a nice looking list, check out the `Downloadable Tools` section.